# creating constant jump table; xcode; clang; asm

Tags: xcode, assembly, switch-statement, clang, jump-table

I have quite strange issue when try to create the jump table in my asm program for iphone (arm64):

```
.globl my_func
my_func:
...
//jump (switch) table
.L.f_switch:
    .short .L.case0 - .L.f_switch
    .short .L.case1 - .L.f_switch
    ...
.L.case0:
//some case code
...
.L.case1:
//other case code
```

After compilation this table is filled by zeros instead of actual values. It could be seen by dumping compiled object file.

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
_my_func:
0000000000000000    adr x4, #16
0000000000000004    ldrh    w5, [x4, x3, lsl #1]
0000000000000008    add x4, x4, w5, uxth
000000000000000c    br  x4
.L.f_switch:
0000000000000010    .long   0x00000000
0000000000000014    .long   0x00000000
0000000000000018    .long   0x00000000
000000000000001c    nop
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: If you do an `objdump -rD file.o` on it does it show relocation information in the table? If it does then the relocation information should be filled in during the link process. If that is what is occurring then the table will be filled with zeroes as place holders.

Comment: @MichaelPetch No, it doesn't. I don't know how this relocation information should look in disassembler to be honest. But "Disassembly of section .text:" is the only string which is not instruction from my original source file here.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed us the relevant output from dumping  the compiled object file.

Comment: You don't say what your target platform is (ARM/X86/X86_64), you tag as XCode (which suggests Apple of some sort). If you target Intel x86-64(or x86), one issue I see is that if you intend to create a jump table then you are going to need absolute addresses. using an indirect `JMP` via a register(like `jmp *.L.f_switch(,%rax,8)`, you need absolute addresses stored in the table. As it is, the lack of real code makes the question off topic.

Comment: If you are in fact using a jump table without absolute addresses I can only conclude you must be targeting ARM64(or ARM) which would suggest iOS, but there is no mention of that in the question.You need to basically rewrite this question with sample code that could be compiled demonstrating the issue,and would be helpful to see the output of _objdump_ on that sample code.A better description of the target CPU/OS would help.  My guess is that the 0s are relocation placeholders that will be filled in later.That could happen if the jump table is in the `.data` section (not in the `.text` section)

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I added related lines from dump into the question. You're right, it's iphone (`ios`, `arm64`) device. Jump table is in `.text` section and for my best knowledge should be filled by compiler (compiler know difference) not linker (there are differences not actual addresses).

Comment: Can you show the output with the -r AND -D options when using objdump.

Comment: I think a question might be why you think this is wrong. Is there a bug you have encountered when running the finally linked image. The compiler doesn't resolve all addresses at compile time and it requests the linker to attempt to resolve any relocations it can handle.

Comment: The jump table in your actual code is `.short` (2 bytes or a half word) but the output of objdump suggests long. Does your output match the code you compiled?

Comment: I think that this is wrong because GCC fill the table by right results straight. Clang linker couldn't resolve the table: `ld: in /file_part/, in section TEXT,text reloc 0: ARM64_RELOC_SUBTRACTOR must have r_length of 2 or 3 for architecture arm64`. So I'm stick with opinion to blame compiler.

Comment: That does look like a relocation warning. Are you saying that you get this warning (and ignore it) and look at the resulting object file?

Comment: `.short` is normal. Disassembler just unite two neighbor elements. Actually `.int` produce just twice as bigger zero' table

Comment: The problem is that I can't tell that because you have yet to produce the original assembler file that was assembled to this object you are viewing. Is there a reason why you refuse to edit the original assembly code to show us how the jump code was defined and used.  For example there is clearly code in the object file but I have no reference point to the actual assembler code it came from

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's not compilation warning, it's linker error. compiler doesn't generate any warnings. And it seems that linker (as well as me) is not happy with the compiler's job.

Comment: You may wish to see this article on creating a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The compiler generates information for the linker to use. It is very possible for assembler code to compile just find but then the linker picks up on a problem after the fact. When it comes to relocation specifically the compiler will fill in an address with zeros (the warning even suggests the compiler generated relocatable entries for the jump table that the linker tried to unsuccessfully resolve). Not everything is resolved at compile time. I don't know enough about ARM64 to say whether it has a special addressing mode that makes the difference between two labels relocatable.

Comment: The reason I want to see -rD on the objdump is to see exactly what relocation the compiler suggested needed to be handled at link time. If you provided an actual Assembler file that I could then compile here and review the output it would make this so much easier thus the request for an MVCE question. Without the original assembler file I can't conclude that this was due to human error (or a compiler bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank Michael Petch for his contribute to this discussion which was very helpful.

Secondly, I want to highlight that the **size of data in jump table** is important. Clang doesn't have any issues with '.word' (4 Byte) offsets. While the troubles are beginning when other '.byte' (1 Byte) or '.short'/'.hword' (2 Byte) offsets are used.

Test 1. **Data type is '.short' (2 Byte)**.

```
my_func:
...
//jump (switch) table
.L.f_switch:
    .short .L.case0 - .L.f_switch
    .short .L.case1 - .L.f_switch
    ...
.L.case0:
//some case code
...
.L.case1:
//other case code
```

the dump is:

```
Relocation information (__TEXT,__text) 10 entries
address  pcrel length extern type    scattered symbolnum/value
00000018 False word   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000018 False word   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case4
00000016 False word   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000016 False word   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case3
00000014 False word   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000014 False word   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case2
00000012 False word   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000012 False word   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case1
00000010 False word   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000010 False word   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case0

(__TEXT,__text) section
_my_func:
0000000000000000 adr x4, #16
0000000000000004 ldrh w5, [x4, x3, lsl #1]
0000000000000008 add x4, x4, w5, uxth
000000000000000c br x4
.L.f_switch:
0000000000000010 .long 0x00000000
0000000000000014 .long 0x00000000
0000000000000018 .long 0x00000000
000000000000001c nop
```

till now is everything is going as Michael described in his answer (except there is reservation for 2 Bytes offset entities)

After that linker returns error:

```
in section __TEXT,__text reloc 0: ARM64_RELOC_SUBTRACTOR must have r_length of 2 or 3 for architecture arm64
```

Please note that there would not be any errors if **4 Bytes** entities were used.

**Test 2.** Could be treated as workaround.

```
    .set case_0,     .L.case0 - .L.f_switch
    .set case_1,     .L.case1 - .L.f_switch
    .set case_2,     .L.case2 - .L.f_switch
    ...

.L.f_switch:
    .hword  case_0
    .hword  case_1
    .hword  case_2
    ...
```

the dump of this approach is:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
_my_func:
0000000000000000 adr x4, #16
0000000000000004 ldrh w5, [x4, x3, lsl #1]
0000000000000008 add x4, x4, w5, uxth
000000000000000c br x4
.L.f_switch:
0000000000000010 .long 0x01200020
0000000000000014 .long 0x06900240
0000000000000018 .long 0x00000cc0
000000000000001c nop
```

As you could notice compiler fills the jump table straight by right offset values. As a result there is not relocation information and any issues with linker.

Also I want to bring attention the the following facts.

- GNU GCC compiler produces the result as in "Test 2" (with filled jump table) for both "Test 1" and "Test 2" code.
- GNU GCC compiler generates error if offset in table could not be fitted in current data type. For example 1 Byte data type is used & offset is bigger than 255. Clang do not generate any errors in such cases so programmer should manually control it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are observing with entries being set to 0 is related to relocation. The compiler may emit relocation information that the linker will ultimately resolve. To that end I created this small sample program:

## test.s

```
.text
.align 4
.globl _main
_main:
    adr  x0, .L.f_switch
    ldr  w1, [x0, x1, LSL#2]
    add  x0, x0, x1
    br   x0

.L.f_switch:
    .word  .L.case0 - .L.f_switch
    .word  .L.case1 - .L.f_switch
    .word  .L.case2 - .L.f_switch

.L.case0:
    nop

.L.case1:
    nop

.L.case2:
    nop

    ret
```

I'm using XCode 7 and clang reports this version info for `clang --version`:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

To simplify things at the command line I set an environment variable to point to my iPhone SDK with:

```
export ISYSROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/"
```

First experiment is to compile `test.s` to `test.o`. I use this command:

```
clang -x assembler  -arch arm64 test.s -o test.o -c
```

Now if I dump test.o with `otool` using:

```
otool -drGtv test.o
```

I get this:

```
test.o:
Data in code table (0 entries)
offset     length kind
Relocation information (__TEXT,__text) 6 entries
address  pcrel length extern type    scattered symbolnum/value
00000018 False long   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000018 False long   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case2
00000014 False long   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000014 False long   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case1
00000010 False long   True   SUB     False     .L.f_switch
00000010 False long   True   UNSIGND False     .L.case0
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000        adr     x0, #16
0000000000000004        ldr     w1, [x0, x1, lsl #2]
0000000000000008        add      x0, x0, x1
000000000000000c        br      x0
.L.f_switch:
0000000000000010        .long   0x00000000
0000000000000014        .long   0x00000000
0000000000000018        .long   0x00000000
.L.case0:
000000000000001c        nop
.L.case1:
0000000000000020        nop
.L.case2:
0000000000000024        nop
0000000000000028        ret
```

The compiler(assembler) has emitted relocation entries for 00000010, 00000014, and 00000018 for both parts of the equation (`.L.case#` and `.L.F_switch`). The table itself is filled with place holder zeros. It will be the linker's job to resolve the relocations. I can manually link the `test.o` above with a command like:

```
ld  -demangle -dynamic -arch arm64 -iphoneos_version_min 5.0.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/ -o test -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk//usr/lib/system test.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a
```

I can now use `otool` to dump the final executable with a command like:

```
otool -drGtv test
```

And get this output:

```
test:
Data in code table (0 entries)
offset     length kind
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100007f80        adr     x0, #16
0000000100007f84        ldr     w1, [x0, x1, lsl #2]
0000000100007f88        add      x0, x0, x1
0000000100007f8c        br      x0
.L.f_switch:
0000000100007f90        .long   0x0000000c
0000000100007f94        .long   0x00000010
0000000100007f98        .long   0x00000014
.L.case0:
0000000100007f9c        nop
.L.case1:
0000000100007fa0        nop
.L.case2:
0000000100007fa4        nop
0000000100007fa8        ret
```

Notice that all the relocations have been resolved by the linker in the final executable.

Alternatively I could have compiled and linked all in one step to produce the executable `test` with a command like:

```
clang -x assembler  -arch arm64 -L$ISYSROOT/usr/lib/system --sysroot=$ISYSROOT test.s -o test
```

I split it up to show what the object file looked like and then the resulting executable after linking.

Comment: Michael thanks for your guide. Everything you described is correct. The difference with my code is I used 2 bytes to keep offsets and it seems that it's exactly where the issue is.